# RaisのomniauthでGoogleログインのコールバック時に403エラーとなる

Tags: ruby-on-rails, centos, nginx, security, url

RaisのomniauthでGoogleログインの実装を行っており、ローカル環境では正常に動作しています。
サーバー環境（CentOS, Nginx）ではGoogleの認証後に以下のようなURLにコールバックされた時、403エラーが表示されてしまいます。

`https://dummy.com/auth/google_oauth2/callback?xxxxxxx&scope=email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com&xxxxx`

**403 Forbiddenの状況**

[image: 403 Forbiddenの状況]

調査を進める中で、omniauthやGoogleログインに関わらず、以下のように「://」を含むURLにアクセスすると、同様のエラーが発生することが分かりました。

（非エンコード）
`https://dummy.com/?a=https://`
（エンコード）
`https://dummy.com/?a=https%3A%2F%2F`

クエリパラメーターに `://` を含むアクセスを禁止するようなサーバーのセキュリティー関係の設定があるのかなと思っているのですが、思い当たる設定がある方がいたら、教えて頂けませんか。

なお、この問題に関するRailsやNginxのエラーログやアクセスログへの出力はありません。

#### 環境

CentOS7
Nginx
Rails

Answer (score 1):

調査の結果、AWSのWAFの設定で `://` を含むURLをブロックしていたのが問題でした。